# Is there an App Engine shared memory or equivalent solution?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building a GAE app that requires a cryptographic key to operate. I would like to avoid storing the key in code or in a persistent datastore, and instead upload the key whenever I start my app so that it will only reside in memory for the duration of the app's lifetime (from the time I upload the key until no instances are running.)

I understand that this is possible to do with a resident backend, but this seems too expensive (cheapest backend is currently 58$/month) just to keep one value in memory and serve it to other instances on demand.

Note that I'm not looking for a general robust shared-memory solution, just one value that is basically written once and read many times. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried MemCache?

Comment: What is the lifetime of your key?

Comment: @Sameer, In Memcache there is no guarantee to the lifetime of the values stored, and (@proppy) I need the key to live for as long as any of my instances is alive. I also need it to "go away" when all my instances die.

I see now that with App Engine, this kind of thinking may be flawed :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this can work the way you hope.  The sources of data in GAE:

1. Files deployed with your app (war or whatever).
2. Per-instance memory (front-end or back-end).
3. Memcache.
4. Datastore (or SQL now, I suppose).
5. Blobstore.
6. Information retrieved via http requests (i.e. store it somewhere else).

1 and 4 are out, as per your question.  2 doesn't work by itself because the starting and stopping of instances is out of your control (it wouldn't scale otherwise), and persistent instances are expensive.  3 doesn't work by itself because Memcache can be cleared at any time.  5 is really no different than the datastore, as it is permanently stored on the Google's servers.  Maybe you could try 6 (store it somewhere else), and retrieve it into per-instance memory during the instance startup.  But I suspect that is no better security-wise (and, for that matter, doesn't match with what you said that you wanted).

Comment: This was pretty much my conclusion. I was hoping that I missed some other option.

Comment: Am I the only one with this kind of requirement? I wanted to create a solution where, even if someone breaks into my account or somehow gets the source code, they won't be able to get a hold of the key and decrypt the data on the server.

Comment: Heh... If someone knew you and your app well enough to hack into it, perhaps they could sneakily replace the code with something that made the data public when you entered it next time!  Anyway, I usually end up putting that kind of data into resource files deployed with the app... Not perfect, but then again, if somebody else owns the hardware, there will always be limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a Memcache and local memory solution might work if you:

1. have your server instances clear the memcached key on exit and
2. existing server instances write/refresh the key regularly (for
   example on every request).

That way the key will  likely be there as long as an instance is operational and most likely not be there when starting up cold.

The same mechanism could also be used to propagate a new key and/or cycle server instances in the event of a key change.

Comment: I considered that, but since I have no control over instances, this solution might introduce a "race" where a new instance is coming up right after clearing the memcache by an instance that was going down. Another thing is that there are no guarantees for the key actually remaining in the memcache while a new instance is coming up, so that's another issue.